# What are the libraries included for type ahead in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

I want to run autocomplete with filtering based on the search in tex tbox. I want to know what are the libraries to be included in the head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solely these will do:

jquery

angularJS

ui-bootstrap

Comment: Thanku . here is the code pen i found, its not working if i include all the above three                                                                           https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv                                                                   what changes i ahve to do?

Comment: It is working completely fine. Try typing 'michigan'

Comment: there its working. but when i use it in my project its not working. kindly suggest what changes and what libraries i have to include for the existing code in code pen. i am a fresher of 3 months exp. and this is the task for me give in training kindly help me.

Comment: What error are u getting in the console? (in your project)

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>                                                                                    i included the above libraries but when i type any letter in the textbox, auto complete not occurring . not even it showing the states names .  in console no errors came

Comment: no error in console. its not showing the data when i type any keyword

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/..                                                                                  how can i use this? the libraries                                                        EXTERNAL RESOURCES LOADED INTO THIS FIDDLE:
jquery-ui.css
angular-1.0.0.js                                                                                                                              how can i add these external resources.pls help me

Comment: Try to exclude jquery. Just include Angular JS first and after that include ui bootstrap. Also u need to add ui.bootstrap as dependency will defining your module